# Angular call a function inside of a function

Tags: angular, function, random

Hi guys I'm trying to create a program that selects a student randomly (the page should show a student randomly by clicking a button "select a student").

I have a mock that contains a list of all of students and a service which removes some students who aren't present, and then save the list of present students that we call saveStudent() in service :

```typescript
  private saveStudent(student: Student) {
    localStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(student));
    
  }
```

Also, I have a Home component that has a random function (but it doesn't work this shows just "hi" in console.):

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { STUDENT, Student } from 'src/app/mock/students.mock';
import { AbsentListService } from 'src/app/services/absent-list/absent-list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private absentListService: AbsentListService) { }

  selectedUser: any;
  student: Student[] = STUDENT;
  absentStudent!: Student[];
  genderMessage: any;


  selectRandomUser() {
    this.selectedUser = this.student[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.student.length)];
    if (this.selectedUser.isWoman) {
      this.genderMessage = ("Tu es la grande gagnante !");
      console.log("femme fonctionne")
    }

    if (this.selectedUser.isWoman === false) {
      this.genderMessage = ("Tu es le grand gagnant !");
      console.log("homme fonctionne")

    }
    else ("Aucun utilisateur n'a été trouvé");
    console.log("hi")

  }
}
```

And finaly my HTML Home :

```html
<main>
    <div class="launch">
        <button (click)="selectRandomUser()"> Select a student </button>
    </div> 

    <div class="white-box-card">
        <div class="white-box"></div>
        
    </div>
</main>
```

My question is: can I call a function "saveStudent()" that exist in service and contains a list of present students inside of the function selectRandomUser() to execute a function which selects a present student randomly.

Thanks a lot

I'm trying to create a program that selects a student randomly (the page should show a student randomly by clicking a button "select a student").

Comment: Hi, welcome to the stackoverflow. If the function `saveStudent` is a part of AbsentListService, you can call it easily anywhere in the HomeComponent. Simply by calling `this.absentListService.saveStudent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call `saveStudent` function when it was a public method in the service for using `saveStudent` remove `private` keyword before `saveStudent` and in your `selectRandomUser` function call the `saveStudent` like this:

```
this.selectRandomUser.saveStudent()
```

Comment: Yes I modified like you said . But I face with a problem of argument(arguments of saveStudent() is not known in .ts) : I have a function in service : `public saveStudent(student: Student) {
    localStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(student));
  }` And I have this function in component.ts : `selectRandomUser() {
    this.absentListService.saveStudent(student:Student);` Of course I imported my service in component in service and for security in component also but notihing works.. I thought when we importe service in component normally we have service's property too

Comment: would you please provide stackblitz link?